# SceneWillConnect to session not called after adding SceneDelegate into an existing project - getting blank screen

Tags: swift, xcode

i have an existing project based on storyboard that works from iOS 12.

I am trying to implement the SceneDelegate class to make some things working on iOS 13 and above but when I launch the app I get a blank a screen.

I did the following:

In my info.plist file I added this code:

```
<key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
<dict>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).SceneDelegate</string>
                <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                <string>Default Configuration</string>
                <key>UISceneStoryboardFile</key>
                <string>Splash</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Since my project is storyboard based I added this to the SceneDelegate class

```
@available (iOS 13.0, *)
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }        
  }
    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene is being released by the system.
    }
    
    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Not called under iOS 12 - See AppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive
    }
    
    func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Not called under iOS 12 - See AppDelegate applicationWillResignActive
    }
    
    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Not called under iOS 12 - See AppDelegate applicationWillEnterForeground
    }
    
    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Not called under iOS 12 - See AppDelegate applicationDidEnterBackground
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Bests